# Multiple definition error when using extern variables

Tags: c++

I'm having a strange multiple definition error and I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a file structure similar to the following:

```
-Folder
---data.cpp
---interface.cpp
---initialize.cpp
---internal.hpp
---maincode.cpp
```

internal.hpp is included in all source code files in this folder. It has 3 extern variables to be used as forward declarations for variables defined in data.cpp, like so:

internal.hpp:

```
namespace montecarlo{

   namespace internal{

      extern std::vector<std::vector<int> > c_octants; 
      extern std::vector<std::vector<int> > b_octants; 
      extern bool mc_parallel_initialized;

   } // end of internal namespace

} // end of montecarlo namespace
```

data.cpp:

```
#include "internal.hpp"

namespace montecarlo{

   namespace internal{

      std::vector<std::vector<int> > c_octants;
      std::vector<std::vector<int> > b_octants; 
      bool mc_parallel_initialized;

   } // end of internal namespace

} // end of montecarlo namespace
```

For some reason this gives a multiple definition error between every file internal.hpp is included in and data.cpp, as if the compiler is treating these extern variables as definitions rather than declarations.

```
obj/montecarlo/interface.o:(.bss+0x30): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::c_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x30): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/interface.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::b_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/interface.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::mc_parallel_initialized'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/mc.o:(.bss+0x30): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::c_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x30): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/mc.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::b_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/mc.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::mc_parallel_initialized'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/mc_moves.o:(.bss+0x30): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::c_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x30): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/mc_moves.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::b_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/mc_moves.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::mc_parallel_initialized'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/cmc.o:(.bss+0xb0): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::c_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x30): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/cmc.o:(.bss+0x90): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::b_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/cmc.o:(.bss+0x80): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::mc_parallel_initialized'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/cmc_mc.o:(.bss+0x70): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::c_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x30): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/cmc_mc.o:(.bss+0x50): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::b_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/cmc_mc.o:(.bss+0x48): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::mc_parallel_initialized'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/monte_carlo_preconditioning.o:(.bss+0x30): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::c_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x30): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/monte_carlo_preconditioning.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::b_octants'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
obj/montecarlo/monte_carlo_preconditioning.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `montecarlo::internal::mc_parallel_initialized'
obj/montecarlo/data.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:177: recipe for target 'serial' failed
make: *** [serial] Error 1
```

I find this truly bizarre as this seems to comply with correct usage of extern and this code builds just fine on 2 other computers, only giving this error on my home desktop.

Comment: Something that should not happen, but it is. Not enough information to be able to tell you why without guessing, so [mcve], please.

Comment: clean up your output directory. maybe some old obtect files are lying around

Comment: Not exactly related to the question, but consider placing [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or `#pragma once` into your headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean up your output directory and build again. Maybe some old object files are lying around.

Sometimes if not files affected by a change are compiled or your build system fails to do it for all dependent files it could happen that some object files still have references and linking fails.

This happens often on some compiles if you use pre-compiled headers.